# How can I connect to a postgresSql Database from My Oracle Apex Application

Tags: postgresql, oracle-apex

I want to write an automation on Oracle Apex that moves data from my oracle table to a table on Postgres database. How do i make this connection to the Postgres database from Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

It's say 2 options:

- On the database side - in that case this isn't an apex question. Apex is just a dev platform that lives on the oracle database, so if you can make it work in the database you can use it in apex. Google "query postgresql from oracle" or "connect oracle to postgresql" for blogs. I'm not familiar with  postgresql so cannot give you more tips here
- the more modern apex way would be to expose your postgresql data over rest and consume it in apex as a rest data source.